# ReferenceError: TextDecoder при тестировании класса на TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, юнит-тесты, mocha

Есть класс, в котором используются `TextDecoder` и `TextEncoder`. Никакие модули в файле класса для их использования не подключаются. Проект на запуск работает.

Класс покрывается тестами с использованием mocha + chai. Так вот, при тестировании этого класса происходит ошибка `ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined` и `ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined`.

Тесты запускаются следующим образом:

```
"test": "mocha --require ts-node/register tests/**/*.ts"
```

Что нужно сделать для работоспособности тестов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением кода `import { TextDecoder } from 'text-encoding'`